# Alternatives to apache benchmark?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx, benchmark

I'd like some tools for ubuntu that I can use to test my server, how much it can handle.

Any suggestions? I've used apache benchmark before, but I'd like to try out something else.

(As a side question, does apache benchmark work if I'm only using nginx?)

Comment: Why is this off topic?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

ab only sends web requests, it doesn't care what the server is that it is testing.  However, it only tests one page.

There is perfmeter, siege, httpload, jmeter and a number of others.

httpload is rather nice since you can feed it a series of URLs that will be tested.

Comment: For convenience: [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html), [perfmeter](http://jperfmeter.sourceforge.net/), [siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/), [http_load](http://www.acme.com/software/http_load/), [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

Comment: I would recommend [hey](https://github.com/rakyll/hey) as it is very easy to install and use.

Answer (score 14):

`ab` is too slow for benchmarking nginx. I'd recommend [`wrk`](https://github.com/wg/wrk). You can easily build it from source.

Comment: thank you! exactly what I was looking for. in compare to others tools like this `wrk` does it's job better

Answer (score 10):

I'd recommend **siege** for easy-to-setup load tests. Additional to apache benchmark  you can give it a list of URLs to load test against.

A simple command like

`siege -d10 -c10 -i -f urls.txt`

and a `urls.txt` like e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/path1
http://www.example.com/path2
```

will run a load test with 10 concurrent users (-c10), wait up to 10 seconds between each call and the next (-d10), and takes randomly (-i) an URL from the file (-f).